# How to do a fast but innacurate InnoDB row count?

Tags: mysql, count, innodb

The FAQ of PHPMyAdmin [has this to say](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq3-11) about its approximate row counts for InnoDB:

> phpMyAdmin uses a quick method to get the row count, and this method only returns an approximate count in the case of InnoDB tables.

I would like to use this 'quick method' - but everywhere I search seems to have a different answer.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They [do this](http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=132167):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'foo';
```

> This returns a 'Rows' column. With
> MyISAM it's 100% accurate, InnoDB just
> guesses. This is why MyISAM is faster
> than InnoDB when doing a 'SELECT
> COUNT(*)' query without a where
> clause.

[phpMyAdmin is open-source](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin), so you can just go into the code and see for yourself!